# R: Inverting second panel of four in multiplot as.zoo

Tags: r

I am able to plot a series of four charts:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("DJIA",src = "FRED")
getSymbols("DGS10",src = "FRED")
getSymbols("T10Y2Y",src = "FRED")


x <- merge(DJIA, DGS10, T10Y2Y)
tail(x)
plot(as.zoo(x),las=1,main="",mgp=c(1,0.5,0),xlab="")
```

but how can I invert the chart in the second panel?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1/T10Y2Y is the reciprocal series.

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do this but I want the inverted series (min on top, max on bottom), not the reciprocal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reverse the scale with the lowest value at top and highest value at bottom  `ylim` can be a list with one component per panel.  Reverse the limits on T10Y2Y panel.  Only components for which the default is to be changed need be specified.

```
ylim <- list(T10Y2Y = range(T10Y2Y, na.rm = TRUE)[2:1])
plot(as.zoo(x), las = 1, main = "", mgp = c(1, 0.5, 0), xlab = "", ylim = ylim)
```